# How to design a DataType in C# that cannot become invalid

Tags: c#, .net

this is a question that can discussed only, but not really answered.

My question is: I have a complex rendering application and with a lot of primitive data types like:

- Color
- FontSize
- FontFamily
- Thickness
- ...

All of them represent a single value, e.g. Color = Value(uint32), FontFamily = Name(string)

I want to design the datatypes in a way, that they cannot become invalid and that you cannot pass invalid values to a method. They should be immutable.

So my first idea, was to define them as structs, but how to handle the initializers (in a struct you cannot override the default constructor and you cannot have initializers for your fields.

For example: The FontSize must be between 4 and 100.

One solution could be the following design:

```
struct FontSize
{
    readonly in size;

    public int Size
    {
        get { return size >= 4 && size <= 100 ? size : DefaultSize; }
    }

    public FontSize(int size)
    {
        Guard.IsBetween(size, 4, 100, nameof(size)); // Throws ArgumentException
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

which means, that

```
FontSize a;
FontSize b = new FontSize(14);
bool equal = a == b; // True
```

Which is a little bit strange.

How would you design data types like this?

EDIT: Sorry, I have missed the point, that I would do validation in the constructor. But the problem with structs is that there is still the default constructor. With classes I can have null References.

So the point is, that you can only have

1. Classes with validation in the constructors => You have to check for Null-Refs and you don't get valid default values for variables and properties

OR

2. Structs with an ugly property to solve the problem with the default constructor. => No Null Refs, but it looks strange to me.

Comment: I think something that's missing in the question is, do you want the calling code to know that an invalid value was set? As Scott said, your approach is good. I would do the validation on setting the value though instead of the get. So probably in a constructor. You just need to decide if you set default value when an invalid one is passed or raise an ArgumentOutOfRangeException that the calling code would need to handle.

Comment: One of the requirements was for the class to be immutable, so the properties should be read-only.

Comment: @Scott - That's correct. Your answer makes sense, but the values still have to be set the first time in a constructor or some create method. I'm just saying that when the instance is being created and the values are being set, the first and only time, invalid values either need to be ignored and replaced with defaults or an exception should be raised.

Comment: I have forgotten the code for the validation in the constructor. I thought it is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is a good thing. If your domain classes are created so that they can't contain invalid data then all of your checking is in one place instead of checking for invalid values wherever the classes are used.

The answer is

- Use read-only properties
- Pass the values used to populate those values in the constructor
- Validate in the constructor

Or if you don't want the validation to exist within the class itself (there could be reasons for that, like much more complicated validations), you could

- Still use read-only properties
- Make the constructor private
- Use a static "create" method. It calls the constructor, creates a new object, validates it (perhaps using some extension method) and then returns either the valid object or throws an exception.

---

Sorry, one more suggestion - I actually like this one best:

- Still use read-only properties
- Make the constructor `internal`
- Create a separate builder class in the same assembly as your type. That class is `public`, but the constructor of your type is `internal`. That way classes outside the assembly can only access the builder class, pass it the parameters, and then it validates the parameters and either creates a class instance or throws an exception.

Pros

- Validation still isn't in your data class
- You can have multiple builder classes with different validation parameters. So if you need a different version of your data class that has different validation requirements you don't have to modify that class - you just create a different builder class or add a method to the existing one. But you always have control over how consumers create your class.

Con

- Because the constructor is `internal` other classes *in the same assembly* can create invalid instances.

Comment: It is a good answer with some very good tipps, but I have formulated the question very badly. The point is: How to design a solution that also solves the problem with null references.

Comment: Which null references?

Comment: If you use classes, you can have null references, isn't it? If you use structs, you cannot have private constructors.

Comment: One option is to ensure that whatever functions you call to return a new FontSize never return null. (Maybe that's just one function, which makes it easier.) They return a value, throw an exception, or return some default value.  ... You can also use code contracts to indicate that a function should never return a null value. That helps more at compile time. Nulls are a pain, and one of the fixes to avoid ever returning null values unless you really need to. That way you don't need to have as many null checks in your code.

Comment: Of course, but when you think about defensive programming you have to check at least the parameters in any public method. I don't like it, so the question is: What is worse: The hack in the datatype or the null guards in every public method.

There are some proposals for non-nullable types, but I guess it will never be a part of the c# language.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your data type is never invalid, there is no way to do this other that making it a class type. If you use a struct, you'll never be able to prevent someone from using the default parameterless constructor, which will initialize all fields to their types' default values. A custom constructor doesn't have this problem, because you can set up validation inside the constructor.

> ```
> FontSize a;
> FontSize b = new FontSize(14);
> bool equal = a == b; // True
> ```
>
> Which is a little bit strange.

Indeed, this looks very odd and may cause a lot of trouble for people using your types. If you insist on using structs, then you may consider adding XML comments (if you're using Visual Studio) to the property stating that a default value will be used if the current value is out of range. This might mitigate the confusion, but surely there will be times when someone doesn't read comments popping up in intellisense.